# Using json builder

Tags: groovy, jsonbuilder

I want something like this in my application with json builder

```
new JsonBuilder() {
            persons.collect{
                [
                        name: it.name,
                        age:  it.age,
                        companies: [{
                                        company1: it.company //The company comes from person object.
                                    },
                                    {
                                        company2: it.company
                                    }
                        ]
                ]
            }
        }
```

Here while accessing the company null pointer exception is being thrown as it is not considering the person iterator.Is there any other way to do it in this way??

Answer (score 0):

you can define the name of `iterator` (closure default parameter name - `it`)

```
new JsonBuilder() {
    persons.collect{person->
        [
            name: person.name,
            age:  person.age,
            companies: [
                {
                    company1: person.company //The company comes from person object.
                },
                {
                    company2: person.company
                }
            ]
        ]
    }
}
```